# GNAT GPS plug-in: Get selected line in Locations

Tags: python, gps, pygtk, gtk3, gnat-gps

I'm doing a [python plug-in](http://docs.adacore.com/gps-docs/users_guide/_build/html/extending.html) to GNAT GPS IDE.

It uses the Locations window to shows a messages to the user, therefore highlighting a file line, like errors do. I use `GPS.Locations.parse()` to add such information, the (somewhat hazy) documentation is [here](http://docs.adacore.com/gps-docs/users_guide/_build/html/GPS.html#gps-filelocation).

The user then could select the line from the code or the Locations window to perform an action.

Get the line from the opened file is a piece of cake.
But one thing that still eludes me, is how I can know which line from the Locations window the user is selecting.
I tried the `GPS.MDI.get("Locations")` which lead me to a maze of children windows objects. I got lost.

So how can I retrieve the text from the currently selected line in Locations?

### Edit

Apparently there [MessageContext](http://docs.adacore.com/gps-docs/users_guide/_build/html/GPS.html#gps-messagecontext) that would give me what I want, but I get an error message saying there's not such class, even when the window has focus. So I recon that the class wasn't instantiated.

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MessageContext'
```

Answer (score 0):

I only saw this thread now. You should call GPS.current_context(), which will return an instance of GPS.Context or one of its children classes. In this case, you can likely use   GPS.current_context().file()

It seems like what you want is to create an entry in the contextual menu in the Locations window. Take a look at the gps_utils.interactive hook. It wraps a python function into a GPS action. This action can then be bound to a specific contextual menu, a keybinding, a menu, a toolbar button,... You can also associate a filter with it, so that the contextual menu also shows up when the action applies (and to implement this filter, you use the above GPS.current_context().file()